# @GetMapping annotation in Spring portlet

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-web

Is `@GetMapping` supported in spring-webmvc-portlet-4.3.1 ? For me it is not and this is what I see when trying to deploy a portlet :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No portlet mode mappings specified -
>   neither at type nor at method level

If not how can we make it support that annotation? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

The exception tells you the portlet mode wasn't specified. That's usually done on the class level:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class MyPortletController { ... }
```

`@GetMapping` or `@PostMapping` don't make sense in case of portlets. With portlets, you usually work with render (`@RenderMapping`), action (`@ActionMapping`) or resource mappings (`@ResourceMapping`).